# Iterating through dictionaries and Accumulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

At the moment, I am attempting to accumulate values in dictionaries nested within a dictionary for homework purposes.

```
a = {
    "Tennis Balls": {
        "User Rating": 15,
        "Available Colors": 5,
        "Location": "Puppy Mart"
    }
}
b = {
    "Squeaky Toy": {
        "User Rating": 48,
        "Available Colors": 3,
        "Location": "Pooch Shop"
    }
}

c = {
    "Stick": {
        "User Rating": 32,
        "Available Colors": 4,
        "Location": "Pooch Shop"
    }
}
d = {
    "Old Shoe": {
        "User Rating": 13,
        "Available Colors": 2,
        "Location": "Puppy Mart"
    }
}
e = {
    "Stuffed Animal": {
        "User Rating": 14,
        "Available Colors": 7,
        "Location": "Dog Express"
    }
}
puppy_toys = {"Toys": [a, b, c, d, e]}

total_user_ratings = 0

for toy in puppy_toys["Toys"]:

    # insert your own code

    individual_user_rating = puppy_toys["Toys"][toy]["User Rating"]
    total_user_ratings += individual_user_rating

print(total_user_ratings)
```

I have to fill in `# your line here` with a single line of code that will allow the for loop to iterate through the dictionary puppy_toys and extract the total number of user ratings for toys located at "Pooch Shop", and then store the total in the variable `total_user_ratings`, but my line of code, shown below, doesn't seem to be working:

`if["Location"] = "Pooch Shop":`

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Make sure that the indentations of the given code are correct. Currently, it is invalid code. Also, put ``` in front and after your code to avoid the hastle with the indentations, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Also, your puppy_toys struct is invalid. Make sure all the brackets are correct.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not very descriptive. As this is homework, I won't solve it for you. Instead, post what the error messages/incorrect behaviour is, and tell us what your thoughts are and what you don't understand.

Comment: the equality operator in python is `==` and that's probably what you were going for. also the `["Location"]` can't come just after the `if` it needs to refer to something. look one line below to get an idea how it should look. Instead of User Rating you're interested in Loaction.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after playing a little, I imagine you want to achieve the sum of User rating by name of Location, so, you have a dictionary with a list actually, correct me if I'm wrong, so you just have to loop it and take the values like this:

```
a = {
    "Tennis Balls": {
        "User Rating": 15,
        "Available Colors": 5,
        "Location": "Puppy Mart"
    }
}
b = {
    "Squeaky Toy": {
        "User Rating": 48,
        "Available Colors": 3,
        "Location": "Pooch Shop"
    }
}

c = {
    "Stick": {
        "User Rating": 32,
        "Available Colors": 4,
        "Location": "Pooch Shop"
    }
}
d = {
    "Old Shoe": {
        "User Rating": 13,
        "Available Colors": 2,
        "Location": "Puppy Mart"
    }
}
e = {
    "Stuffed Animal": {
        "User Rating": 14,
        "Available Colors": 7,
        "Location": "Dog Express"
    }
}
puppy_toys = {"Toys": [a, b, c, d, e]}

total_user_ratings = 0

for toy in puppy_toys["Toys"]:
    shop = list(toy.values())[0]
    if (shop["Location"] == "Pooch Shop"):
        individual_user_rating = shop["User Rating"]
        total_user_ratings += individual_user_rating

print(total_user_ratings)
```

Comment: Got it! Figured it out with “If toy[“Location”] == “Pooch Shop:”

Comment: @Tabla841 fantastic I have always loved to help

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code has two main problems. Let's go over it:

```py
if["Location"] = "Pooch Shop":
```

First, you are trying to compare between two expressions. This is done in python with the equality operator which is `==`. A single `=` usually stands for assignment.

### Ex:

```py
>>> a = 5
>>> print(a)
5
>>> print(a == 5)  # "is a equal to 5?"
True
```

---

The second problem is `if["Location"]`.

In Python the square brackets usually are used as a "getter". A way to acces elements inside an object (like a list or a dictionary).

### Ex:

```py
>>> a = ["x", "y", "z"]
>>> print(a[1])
y
>>> b = {"name": "Tomer", "age": 29}
>>> print(b["name"])
Tomer
```

So you would want the `["Location"]` to come after some object.

A hint for what that should be is in the next line of code:

```py
individual_user_rating = puppy_toys["Toys"][toy]["User Rating"]
```